# Why Output not prints on browser

Tags: java, html, http, webserver

I am writing a code for web server, that shows some particular folder to all clients, and can access all the files in it.

I wrote all the code perfectly, but it didn't print the list of folders that comes under current directory. I aqm posting that module, please tell me why it didn't print the list of all folders or files that comes under current directory.

Let us suppose, our current directory's absolute path is as follows,

```
C:\Users\aMpliFieR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FileBasedServer_Understanding
```

**The code that prints all the folders and files in the browsers is,**

```
void listDirectory(File dir, PrintStream ps) throws IOException {

    ps.println("<html><body align=center>");
    ps.println("<center> Simple File Based MultiThreaded WebServer</center >");
    ps.println("<table border=1 align=center>");
    ps.println("<tr bgcolor=#9999CC><td width=100% height=100% align=center>Directory Listing</td >");
    ps.println("<td width=40% height=40% align=center>Type</td ></tr> ");
    String[] list = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; list != null && i < list.length; i++) {

        File f = new File(dir, list[i]);
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            ps.println("<tr><td>");
            ps.println("< td face= 'Verdana'> <a href='" + f + "'>list</a></td>");
            //ps.println("<td align=\"center\"><a href=\"" + f + "\">list</a>");
            ps.println("</td");
            ps.println("</tr>");
        } /*else {
        ps.println("<tr><td>");
        ps.println(""2""\"" face="\"""Verdana""\""> <A HREF=\""list"\">"list"<A HREF=\""list"\">\n
        </td>");
        ps.println("<td align=center><a href=\""list"/\"><img src=\"""/images/file.gif""\"></img>");
        ps.println("</tr>");
        }*/
    }
    ps.println("</table>");
    ps.println("</body></html>");
}
```

When I run `http://localhost:8080\`, it didn't show anything on browser. Tell me where I am wrong in this module.

**EDIT NO. 1**

> C:\Users\aMpliFieR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FileBasedServer_Understanding\build
>   C:\Users\aMpliFieR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FileBasedServer_Understanding\build.xml
>   C:\Users\aMpliFieR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FileBasedServer_Understanding\manifest.mf
>   C:\Users\aMpliFieR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FileBasedServer_Understanding\nbproject
>   C:\Users\aMpliFieR\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FileBasedServer_Understanding\src

**Edit No.2**

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at filebasedserver_understanding.Worker.handleClientRequest(Worker.java:94)
    at filebasedserver_understanding.Worker.run(Worker.java:57)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Did u try debugging code? is the code reaching `if` inside `for` loop?

Comment: YEs it reaches inside the for loop, and it prints the list of folders and files . It shows output shown in EDIT NO. 1

Comment: Is the printstream working? The first println's work?

Comment: There's not of reasons why this might not work, like you've not terminated the output properly or not implemented the http protocol properly...

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida Yes it prints absolute path on the browser, if I print, `ps.println(f.getAbsolutePath())`.

Comment: How you are getting `PrintStream` and how you are writing it to the `HttpResponse` ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think there is a problem in writing the `ps.println()`,, because if I print some contant insted of that, then it prints correct on the browser.

Comment: @sanbhat I just write anything using `ps.println`. It reflects whatever it has on the browser of client.

Comment: Your HTML is ordered wrong, the title is out side the HTML tag, there is an open HR tag as well...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I make the order correct by removing title, and last line. See the code now. I think I have to make some changes in the If block.

Comment: Also, your missing a closing tr

Comment: @MadProgrammer When I add </tr> , it shows one Exception. I posted that in edit no. 2

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think the problem is very small, but I can't detect where is that problem. Can we do a small chat please, if you have some time. Its a humble request to you.

Comment: Sounds look you're terminating the output correctly, the read socket is expecting more input then it's getting

Comment: @MadProgrammer Then tell what can I do now ?? But if I take a file instead of directory then my code works fine.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I solved above problem, now all the contents shown in a table. This time, I can open any file from current directory, but when I try to open directory, it opens correctly, but if I open any folder or file, it cannot able to open, because there is `favicon.ico` automaticlly appended in the path and it throws `404`, how can I resolve this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please help me, I solved previous problem, please read above comment.